# Nothing happens when I try to open Module in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am running macros on daily basis and yesterday everything worked normally. Today, when one macro invokes another from the file lets say "file.xlsm" i have error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Cannot run the macro "file.xlsm!MacroAll'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

So, I went to developer mode and I realized that there is a list of modules, but when I try to open any of them just nothing happens. I have all the macros enabled, everything from security perspective is turned off. How can I make these modules again openable?

Comment: Sounds like it's corrupted.  Can you go back to a previous version?  Right-click the file in _Explorer > Properties > Previous Versions_.